# Error in compiling curl with openssl1.1.1i

Tags: curl

Below is the error I am getting when compiling curl with openssl1.1.1i static libs.

```
In file included from /home/administrator/Development/myapp/thirdparty/curl/lib/curl_setup.h:76:0,
                 from /home/administrator/Development/myapp/thirdparty/curl/lib/altsvc.c:26:
/home/administrator/Development/myapp/build/thirdparty/curl/lib/curl_config.h:1033:19: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 #define in_addr_t unsigned long
                   ^

/home/administrator/Development/myapp/thirdparty/curl/lib/curl_config.h:1033:28: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 #define in_addr_t unsigned long
                            ^

myapp/thirdparty/curl/lib/CMakeFiles/libcurl.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'myapp/curl/lib/CMakeFiles/libcurl.dir/altsvc.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [myapp/thirdparty/curl/lib/CMakeFiles/libcurl.dir/altsvc.c.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What is the curl version you are compiling? Also are you using any libcurl ?

Comment: I took latest github libcurl version for building